# Add json object to log4j2 when is JSONLayout

Tags: java, json, log4j2

I will show log4j2 with [JSONLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout) same as object on messages.
for example my config of is:

> cat log4j2.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="Json" fileName="/home/jeus/log/loggerjson/main.log" bufferedIO="true" advertiseURI="file://home/jeus/log/loggerjson/main1.log" advertise="true">
        <JSONLayout compact="true" locationInfo="true" complete="false" eventEol="true" properties="true" propertiesAsList="true"/>
    </File>       
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="Json"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

my out put Output:

> cat /home/jeus/log/loggerjson/main.log

```json
{
 "timeMillis":1502359773290,
 "thread":"main",
 "level":"INFO",
 "loggerName":"com.jeus.logger.json.loggerjson.Main",
 "message":"This message is a raw",
 "endOfBatch":false,
 "loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
 "contextMap":[  ],
 "threadId":1,
 "threadPriority":5,
 "source":{  
     "class":"com.jeus.logger.json.loggerjson.Main",
     "method":"main",
     "file":"Main.java",
     "line":61
      }
}
```

i add a json object to log but not show the json object in messages and show that with **\"** charecter

> JSON object:

```json
{"line_id": 12,"play_name":"Jeus"}
```

> my code to log:

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {

       private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

       public static void main(String[] args) {


            String message = "{\"line_id\": 12,\"play_name\": \"Jeus\"}";
            LOGGER.info(message);

        }
 }
```

output is:

```json
{  
 "timeMillis":1502361394238,
 "thread":"main",
 "level":"INFO",
 "loggerName":"com.jeus.logger.json.loggerjson.Main",
 "message":"{\"line_id\": 12,\"play_name\": \"Jeus\"}",
 "endOfBatch":false,
 "loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
 "contextMap":[  

 ],
 "threadId":1,
 "threadPriority":5,
 "source":{  
    "class":"com.jeus.logger.json.loggerjson.Main",
    "method":"main",
    "file":"Main.java",
    "line":62
    }
 }
```

but i will show message as a json object same this:

```json
 "message":{"line_id": 12,"play_name":"Jeus"},
```

Comment: There may be a way to do this, not sure. Please ask on the log4j-user mailing list to get input from the full Log4j2 community.

Comment: I think it will show \ (backslash) before " (double quotation mark), otherwise, generated log file would not be a valid JSON file.

Comment: Another reason is log4j uses Jackson for logging log message in JSON format and If you write json string on output stream, backslash would be there to escape double quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem possible to do with the built-in JsonLayout. No matter what I try it just does a toString on the field rather than serializing it correctly.

One solution is to use the PatternLayout and format it like JSON.

```
log4j.appender.frontEndAudit.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.frontEndAudit.layout.ConversionPattern={"timestamp": 
"%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSSS}", "class": "%C", "file": "%F", "level" : 
"%5p", "line_number" : "%L", "logger_name": "frontEndAuditLog", "mdc": 
"ipAddress": "%X{ipAddress}", "requestId":"%X{requestId}", 
"sessionId":"%X{sessionId}"}, "message": %m, "method": "%M", 
"source_host":"%X{sourceHost}", "thread_name": "%t" }%n
```

This was for log4j1 but same concept would work for log4j2

Comment: Instead of "ipAddress": "%X{ipAddress}", "requestId":"%X{requestId}" if I just add %X then should not it print entire values? like "ipAddress": "actaulIP", "requestId":"givenRequestID" ? I want something like this because my MDC values are dynamic but it's not working in log4j1.2 properties file .

Comment: How to specify JSONFormatter pattern in log4j.properties     ?                                                                                                                                                                                                         log4j.appender.REPORTSLOG = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.REPORTSLOG.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.REPORTSLOG.File = ../logs/ReportLog.log
log4j.appender.REPORTSLOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%m - ReportName=%X{ReportName} JNDI=%X{ReportJNDI}%n

Answer (score 1):

• In log4j2.xml, set the objectMessageAsJsonObject option:

```
<JSONLayout objectMessageAsJsonObject="true" [...] />
```

• Use ObjectMessage (sample code, with jackson):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.ObjectMessage;

JsonNodeFactory f = JsonNodeFactory.instance;
JsonNode event = f.objectNode()
    .put("eventName", "abc")
    .set("person", f.objectNode()
        .put("firstName", "John")
        .put("lastName", "Doe")
    );

// "message":{"eventName":"abc","person":{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"}}
logger.info(new ObjectMessage(event));

// "message":"{\"eventName\":\"abc\",\"person\":{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\"}}"
logger.info(new ObjectMessage(event.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out [LogstashLayout](https://github.com/vy/log4j2-logstash-layout) is a custom layout that does the trick.

1. Write `"message": "${json:message:json}"` in `LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json` file.
2. You have to log a Java object which implements the `MultiformatMessage` and return the JSON string in `getFromattedMessage` method.
3. `getMessageFormats()` method also must return `JSON`.

Comment: FYI - LogstashLayout has moved into Log4j and will be included in the 2.14.0 release as JsonTemplateLayout.

Comment: @rgoers Since it is not released yet, I had to show the solution with `LogstashLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

log4j-layout-template-json is available with version 2.14.0 and works flawlessly using MapMessage.Just add below gradle dependencies if using gradle

```
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.14.0'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.14.0'
compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-layout-template-json:2.14.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.10.0'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-databind:2.10.0'
```

log4j2.yaml looks like

```
Configuration:
  name: Default
  Appenders:
   Console:
    name: LogToConsole
    target: SYSTEM_OUT    
    JsonTemplateLayout:
      eventTemplateUri: "classpath:LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json"
  Loggers:
   AsyncRoot: 
     level: info
     additivity: false
     AppenderRef:
         - ref: LogToConsole
```

Then extend MapMessage for the object(MyMapMessage) you want to log and use

```
private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(YourClass.class);
LOGGER.error(myMapMessage.getData());
```